# Kafka Streams Topology different keys but same schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams topology in which I am joining 5 tables, each being created over a topic that is populated by some Kafka Connectors producing KeyValue events where Key is produced with respect to the same Avro schema, but in my topology, when I am joining the tables it seems that the Key are not the same, event if they are Java equals. What is the reason behind all these?

It is integrated with Confluent Schema Registry.

We have used the debugger and we have seen at debug time that two keys received on different topics but with the same value are equals. But at the same time, if a lookup in the store build on top of topic B with the key received on topic A is performed it will not match something.

```
fun streamsBuilder(): StreamsBuilder {
    val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder()
    val productsStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, Aggregate>(streamNameRepository.inputWebshopProductsTopic)
    val productPricesStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, PriceVariantsHolder>(streamNameRepository.productsPricesStreamTopic)
    val productsRatingsStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, Aggregate>(streamNameRepository.inputProductRatingsTopic)
    val inputProductsStockStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, Aggregate>(streamNameRepository.inputProductsStockTopic)

    val productsStockStream =
            inputProductsStockStream.map { key, value -> toKeyValue(key, productStockMapper.aStockQuantity(value)) }
    productsStockStream.to(streamNameRepository.productsStockStreamTopic)

    streamsBuilder.globalTable<Key, StockQuantity>(streamNameRepository.productsStockStreamTopic,
            Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.productsStockGlobalStoreTopic))

    val saleProductsTable = productsStream
            .filter { _, aggregate -> aggregate.payload != null }
            .map { key, aggregate -> toKeyValue(key, saleProductMapper.aSaleProduct(aggregate) { productsStockStore().get(Key(it)) }) }
            .mapValues { saleProduct -> log.debug("received $saleProduct"); saleProduct; }
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce({ _, saleProductAvro -> saleProductAvro }, Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.saleProductsStoreTopic))

    val productPricesTable = productPricesStream
            .map { key, aggregate -> toKeyValue(key, aggregate) }
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce({ _, price -> price }, Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.productsPricesStoreTopic))

    val productsRatingsTable = productsRatingsStream
            .map { key, aggregate -> toKeyValue(key, productRatingMapper.aProductRating(aggregate)) }
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce({ _, aggregate -> aggregate }, Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.productsRatingsStoreTopic))

    val productsStockTable = productsStockStream
            .map { key, aggregate -> toKeyValue(key, aggregate) }
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce { _, aggregate -> aggregate }

    val productsInNeedOfVariantStockUpdate = productsInNeedOfVariantStockUpdate(productsStockTable, saleProductsTable)

    saleProductsTable
            .outerJoin(productPricesTable, saleProductMapper::aPricedSaleProduct)
            .outerJoin(productsRatingsTable, saleProductMapper::aRatedSaleProduct)
            .outerJoin(productsStockTable, saleProductMapper::aQuantifiedSaleProduct)
            .outerJoin(productsInNeedOfVariantStockUpdate, saleProductMapper::aSaleProductWithUpdatedVariantStock)
            .toStream()
            .filter { _, saleProductAvro -> saleProductAvro.id != null }
            .mapValues { value -> log.debug("publish {}", value); value; }
            .to(streamNameRepository.outputSaleProductsTopic)

    return streamsBuilder
}

private fun <V> toKeyValue(key: Key, value: V): KeyValue<Key, V> {
    return KeyValue(Key.newBuilder(key).build(), value)
}
```

Comment: @DinaBogdan: Glad you found a workaround; sounds reasonable to me. Other alternatives (not really better) are to "strip the magic byte" or use a different data type for the join-key (eg, some POJO). Hence, all those approaches are similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate with Confluent Schema Registry, the magic byte for each topic would be different and thus the join won't work as expected (as the key comparison happens on byte level...)

It is kind of expected. This issue comes up once in a while and it's tricky to resolve natively (ie, built-in) within Kafka Streams, because Confluent Schema Registry is a third party tool, and Kafka Streams should be agnostic to it.

There are workarounds though.

A workaround would be re-mapping every key that we receives inside the topology into a new Key and now all the keys in the topology are produced with the same Avro Schema (the same Avro Schema by schema id).

Other alternatives (not really better) are to "strip the magic byte" or use a different data type for the join-key (eg, some POJO). Hence, all those approaches are similar.

Comment: I've read that the magic byte is always 0, so how every topic can have another magic byte? My understanding is that magic byte is related to the data format (which in my case is AVRO) not to the topic... Could you provide me more details, please?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Would be nice to have your word on the above Community Wiki answer. Danke schon.